# Attempted proofs of P vs NP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

What are the most recent (say in the last 3 years) attempts at disproving $P = NP$, and where can I find the papers?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I assume the downvotes (not me) because most such attempts have an obvious flaw in them and do not really add to our understanding of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the search feature of arXiv?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last such serious attempt was likely Norbert Blum's attempted proof of P $\neq$ NP in 2017.  Not long after it was submitted to arxiv, it was discovered to have a serious (but nontrivial) flaw.

This proof was discussed on stackexchange [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38803/is-norbert-blums-2017-proof-that-p-ne-np-correct) (and in more detail [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38886/tardos-function-counterexample-to-blums-p-neq-np-claim)), and on several blogs (like [Godel's Lost Letter](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2017/08/17/on-the-edge-of-eclipses-and-pnp/)).

Answer (score 21):

Gerhard Woeginger has an up-to-date page with all attempts to (dis)prove the *P* vs *NP* question:
https://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm

Comment: thanks but i already know that page and it stop in 2016...

Comment: @Yamar69 If you already knew about this page, you should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: This important page is now gone - it is replaced with a redirect to https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10951-022-00748-4

Comment: The page is back, but obviously unmaintained. Did anyone take over the updating of such an archive?

Comment: Here is a fairly new try … https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.09512.